# enquo() error in function: the argument has already been evaluated

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to write several embedded functions that end up filtering a set of columns (`id_type` in `filter_data()`) that is defined by a vector (`id_types` in `load_data()`).  Based on the new [dplyr programming vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), I'm trying to use `enquo` to make my code run, but am getting an error that I don't know how to deal with.

The actual code is more complicated (and actually requires the different functions), but this is the simplest code I can use to replicate the error:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data <- tibble(id_a = c(1,1,2,2,3),
             id_b = 991,
             id_c = c(45,45,45,1,80),
             units_sold = c(21,20,24,4,5))
id_types <- c("id_a", "id_b", "id_c")

load_data <- function(){

  bind_rows(pmap(list(list(data),
                  id_types),
             filter_data))
}

filter_data <- function(df, id_type) {
  quo_id_type <- enquo(id_type)

  filter(df, !!quo_id_type == 1)
}

load_data()
```

throws the following error:

```
Error in (function (x, strict = TRUE)  : 
  the argument has already been evaluated
Called from: (function (x, strict = TRUE) 
    {
    caller_env <- parent.frame()
    if (identical(caller_env, globalenv())) {
        stop("must be called in a function")
    }
    if (missing(x)) {
        stop("argument \"x\" is missing")
    }
    .Call(rlang_capturearg, NULL, NULL, pairlist(caller_env, 
        strict), get_env())
})(id_type)
```

My desired output: I want the code to iterate through all the `id_types`, filtering `df` where either `id_a == 1`, `id_b == 1`, or `id_c == 1` (rows 1, 2, and 4 on the original df), and bind those together in a new data frame.

How can I get this code to work without removing the nested functions?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to change `enquo` to `quo` and fix `quo_id_type` to be `quo_id_types` to match your name.

Comment: `quo(id_type)` does run, but it doesn't properly filter.  I believe that in the filter(), its evaluating literally `~id_type == 1`, which is always false and returns 0 rows.

Comment: I think you have a typo in this example. I get the error `'quo_id_type' not found`. In the `filter_data` function you have a version of that variable with and without the "s"

Comment: And what exactly is the desired output here?

Comment: Fixed the typo (though the error still happens at `quo_id_type <- enquo(id_type)`) and added my desired output.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why the original code didn't work, but I did find another solution.

Replace this:

```
quo_id_type <- enquo(id_type)

filter(df, !!quo_id_type == 1)
```

With this:

```
filter_at(df, vars(id_type), all_vars(. == 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Quick fix:

If you need the `filter_data` function, you can switch to this, which is a bit easier and more obvious (`.data` refers to your `df` you pass into `filter`, and `[[` selects the `id_type` column when `id_type` is a string):

```
filter_data <- function(df, id_type) {
  filter(df, .data[[id_type]] == 1)
}
```

If you can drop the `filter_data` function altogether, you can go with:

```
filter_at(data, vars(id_types), any_vars(. == 1))
```

(Also dropping the `bind_rows` and `pmap` calls). Note that you'll need to change `all_vars` to `any_vars`, since you're evaluating all of the vars in `id_types` at once.

### Why the original won't work:

In this example, the argument you pass to `filter` is a string (i.e., "id_a"), but even this by itself won't work:

```
> filter(data, "id_a" == 1)
# A tibble: 0 x 4
# ... with 4 variables: id_a <dbl>, id_b <dbl>, id_c <dbl>,
#   units_sold <dbl>
```

The filter condition evaluates to `FALSE`, since the string `"id_a"` is not equal to the integer `1`, so no rows satisfy the condition, so it returns an empty `tibble`.

---

The argument you pass to the function is really `id_types[[1]]`, not "id_a", so that's what you're `enquo()`ing. You can see that by trying:

```
f <- function(id_type) enquo(id_type)  
f(id_types[[1]])  
f("id_a")
```

Which returns:

```
<quosure: global>
~id_types[[1]]
<quosure: empty>
~"id_a"
```

---

You can fix that (and print the other problem) by changing `filter_data` to this (but I wouldn't recommend actually doing this):

```
filter_data <- function(df, id_type) {
  id_type <- id_type
  quo_id_type <- enquo(id_type)
  print(quo(filter(df, !!quo_id_type == 1)))

  filter(df, !!quo_id_type == 1)
}
```